# Can I iterate over the query string parameters using ExpressJS?

Tags: node.js, express

I know that if I pass a URL like the below:

```
http://localhost:3000/customer?companyid=300&customerid=200
```

That I can then in ExpressJS use the below to extract the data:

```
res.send(util.format('You are looking for company: %s  customer: %s', req.query.companyid, req.query.customerid));
```

But, I would like to iterate over the paramters and handle them without having to predefine them in my query.  I can't seem to find anything in the Express API, etc that seems to work (probably looking right over it).

```
http://localhost:3000/customer?companyid=300&customerid=200&type=employee
```

Any comments / suggestions would be appreciated!

Thanks,

S

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In JavaScript you can look over the properties of an object using a for loop:

```
for (var propName in req.query) {
    if (req.query.hasOwnProperty(propName)) {
        console.log(propName, req.query[propName]);
    }
}
```

The `hasOwnProperty` check is to make sure that the property is not from the objects prototype chain.

Answer (score 8):

`req.query` is just an object, so you can iterate over it like you would any object, e.g.

```
for (var param in req.query) {
   console.log(param, req.query[param]);
}
```